# What is the difference between 原因 and 要因, 解析 and 分析?

Tags: word-usage

When I search meaning, both 原因 and 要因 mean **cause**.

解析 and 分析 mean **analysis**.

But I think there will be little different meaning.

Comment: There's also 起因 which is similar to 原因 and used (mostly?) in writing, but it has a different usage pattern in terms of particles.

Comment: I suggest you break this question in two: one for the difference between 要因、原因(、起因) and another one with 解析、分析（、解剖）.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my personal experience,

**「原因」** is like a general cause, perhaps one of many.

```
「原因は結果の反対語である」 - "The cause is the opposite of the result"
```

**「要因」** is the primary cause.

```
「他の原因はたくさんあったのですが、飲酒運転が要因だったようです。」 
  - "Though there were many other factors, drunk driving seems to have been the primary cause"
```

**「解析」** is a word for the process of developing a logical theory about how something works or how or why something happened by analyzing the information already available, like when you analyze statistics.

```
「経済を解析するプロジェクト」 - "a project to analyze the economy"
```

**「分析」** is a general word for breaking something up and analyzing its parts to get more information about it, like you might analyze a meteorite.

```
「事故の原因はまだ分析しなければなりません」 
  - "(We) still need to analyze the causes of the accident"
```

Comment: It might also be worth noting that 原因 is very often used for causes for negative/undesired results.  Eg see many of the examples at http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/69163/example/m0u/%E5%8E%9F%E5%9B%A0/